Why does TS allow interface multiple inheritance?
I'm learning TypeScript about extending the interface. I unintentionally recognized that TypeScript allows extending interface from multiple classes. That made me surprised and I have researched a lot to find more information about but until now, I have not been able to answer questions.
I am wondering that: although TypeScript prevents class inheriting from multi-classes (class has 2 or more direct base classes), why does it permit one interface to  extend directly from multiple classes like that code below:

    class Student{
        name:string = ''
    }
    
    class Employee {
        salary:number =0
    }
    
    interface Work_Study extends Student,Employee{
        description:string;
    }
    


It's basically recycling existing types, the use case will depend on what/how you're trying to achieve. It's pretty commonly used indeed.

"one interface that extends directly from multiple classes like in the code below" - it doesn't. The interface extends multiple types - it doesn't care how those types were defined. They might be declared with class, interface, or type. The interface does not care (or know) about the definitions (implementations) of the class methods.

"Is it often used as an alternative to class multiple inheritance" - no. Notice that your Work_Study_Student is neither a subclass of Student nor a subclass of Employee - it does not inherit their methods, and instanceof will return false. All it does is to declare that it is compatible with some types.

Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Do you accept that interface Foo {a: string}; interface Bar {b: number}; interface Baz extends Foo, Bar {} is allowed in TypeScript? Or do you need that explained too? I'm wondering whether the question is "why does TS allow multiple inheritance in the type system at all" or if it is specifically "why does TS allow multiple inheritance from class instance types"? They have different answers; please [edit] to clarify which of those questions you're asking.

@Bergi according to your view, All things behind the scenes when an interface extends from multiple classes  is simply copy structure ( signatures if members are method) of members in all classes ( that is extended by the interface) and then merge it in order to create new contact type ( interface).  and that is true when replace class by interface or type alias?

@jcalz I accept that interface Foo {a: string}; interface Bar {b: number}; interface Baz extends Foo, Bar {} is allowed in typescript and that is simply copy structure of Foo and Bar, merging the two structures in order to create new contract namely Baz. But I do not sure that when interface extend class, Can you help me make it clear?

Maybe you want to [edit] to something like "what does it mean when an interface extends a class in TypeScript?". The answer looks like "class X {} introduces two things named X into scope. One is the JS class constructor value X that exists at runtime, and the other is the class instance interface type X that exists only in TS's type system. The latter is what you are referring to with interface Y extends X {}.  Thus you can freely extend multiple class instance types, since they are just interfaces. You are not touching the classes at runtime. Does that make it clear?

@jcalz, what is class instance interface type? what is it purpose in typescript? can you make it clear? Since this is the first time I hear this keyword, I have quickly searched Google but I did not find the answer.

I mean that if you write declare class X {y: string; z: number} it behaves very much like interface X { y: string; z: number }; declare const X: new () => X;. A class declaration declares an interface-like type corresponding to the class instance type, and a const-like value corresponding to the constructor. The instance type isn't literally an interface, but it behaves almost exactly like one. And when you write interface W extends X {} that X is the type, not the value. Does that make it clear? I'm happy to write an answer but I want to make sure it applies first.

@jcalz When I write interface W extends X, Y, Z... {}  in that X, Y, Z they can be either Interface, class, or even type alias?

@jcalz Your explanation is very obvious Before you write an answer, I wonder that: When class extends class A {};  class B extend A {} typescript will do 2 things, the first thing is extending interface type of instance A by interface type B like interface B extend A {}. The second thing it does is inheritance works ( [[Prototype]] inheritance stuff) which is related to constructor values and runtime (javascript action). is it True?

@jcalz Can I state that: " In typescript, only class extend is seen to be inheritance, interface extend is just simple merge type structure to create a new contract ( interface type). "

Your summary is mostly correct but I wouldn't use such terminology. I would say that interface B extends A {} is also "inheritance", but it is inheritance of the types, and there's no problem with multiple inheritance because there's no implementation to worry about. Multiple inheritance of implementations is potentially confusing, because then something has to choose which implementation to inherit from. But when it's just types, you can easily inherit from both. So, can I write the answer now? Are we on the same page? Or am I still missing anything.

@jcalz are three summaries correct?

@jcalz Thank you for your explanation, it is really awesome, Could you write the answer?

I will do that soon.

When you write a class declaration in TypeScript like
class Student {
    name: string = ''
}

it brings into scopes two things named Student.  One is the class constructor value that exists at runtime in JavaScript. It's an object named Student and you can write new Student() to construct a new class instance value.  The other is the class instance type that exists only in TypeScript's type system. It's a type named Student and you can write let student: Student to tell TypeScript that the type of student is the instance type of the Student class.  Even though they share a name and are related, they are not the same thing.
TypeScript doesn't get confused about which thing you're referring to because values and types live in different syntactic contexts in TypeScript. If you write x = new X(), that X is definitely a value, not a type. If you write let x: X;, that X is definitely a type, not a value. If you write interface Z extends X {}, that X is definitely a type, not a value.
See the TypeScript handbook documentation for more details.

It's also important to note that the class instance type behaves exactly like an interface.  It's not declared using the interface keyword, but it behaves the same.  Indeed, the Student declaration above is quite similar to the pair
interface Student {
  name: string
}

const Student: new () => Student = class {
  name: string = ""
};

where the two things named Student are defined explicitly and separately.

If we put those together, we can understand what
class Student {
  name: string = ''
}

class Employee {
  salary: number = 0
}

interface Work_Study extends Student, Employee {
  description: string;
}

is doing. The interface declaration with the extends clause is just declaring a new interface which inherits from the Student and Employee types.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with the Student and Employee constructors.  It's exactly the same as
interface Student {
  name: string
}

interface Employee {
  salary: number;
}

interface Work_Study extends Student, Employee {
  description: string;
}

And multiple inheritance of interfaces is unproblematic.

On the other hand, something like
class Work_Study extends Student, Employee {
  description: string = "oops"
}

is different, in that it's a class declaration and involves the value space. It's invalid because that's the JavaScript extends clause which only allows extending a single parent class. Multiple inheritance in JavaScript classes is prohibited (to avoid the diamond problem where it's ambiguous which implementation to use).
While class Work_Study extends Student, Employee {} and interface Work_Study extends Student, Employee {} look similar, they are in completely different syntactic contexts, and behave differently.  The former is illegal multiple class inheritance, while the latter is legal multiple interface inheritance.
Playground link to code

If the TypeScript supported multiple inheritance of classes, the diamond problem would be possible.
class A {
    f() {
        // Some implementation
    }
}

class B extends A {
    f() {
        // Overridden implementation of A.f()
    }
}

class C extends A {
    f() {
        // Overridden implementation of A.f()
    }
}

class D extends B, C {
    // Do not override the implementation of f()
}

let d: D = new D();
d.f(); // It is not clear which function to call (from A, B, or C).

In the case of interface inheritance, this problem does not arise.
class A {
    f() {
        // Some implementation
    }
}

class B {
    f() {
        // Some implementation
    }
}

interface C extends A, B {

}

// You CANNOT instantiate an interface!
// let c:C = new C();

// You must create an implementation of the С
class CImpl implements C {
    f(): void {
        // And you are required to implement f().
    }
}

let c:C = new CImpl();
// In this case, there is no ambiguity as in the case of class inheritance.
c.f();


In general, using inheritance is often considered a bad practice. There are several good practices that you need to remember:

Interface segregation principle (ISP): "No code should be forced to depend on methods it does not use".

Composition reuse principle (CRP): "Classes should favor polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (by containing instances of other classes that implement the desired functionality) over inheritance from a base or parent class."


You are not allowed to use multiple inheritance to avoid the diamond problem and to encourage developers to adhere to the CRP principle. This  is a design decision by the ECMAScript committee about inheritance in JavaScript.
About your question 1. You are allowed to extend multiple interfaces to comply with the ISP. For example:
interface Disposable {
  dispose: () => void;
}

interface Serializable {
  serialize: () => string;
}

class Student implements Disposable, Serializable {
    name:string = '';
    somethingElse: number = 0;
    serialize() {
      return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
    dispose() {
      // dispose logic
    }
}

If you were allowed to only implement one interface, you would encourage developers to break the ISP principle.
Using multiple interfaces means that when you implement other parts of your application, these parts don't need to be coupled with Student; they can be coupled only with the methods that they need:
function cleanUp(something: Disposable) {
  something.dispose();
}

function serialzie(something: Serializable) {
  return something.serialize();
}

In relation to your questions 2 and 3:

Yes, implementing multiple interfaces is common. Here is an example in the TypeScript code itself.

Yes, same as 2. There is only one limitation, the diamond problem:


interface Student {
    name:string;
    somethingElse: number;
}

interface Employee {
    salary:number;
    somethingElse: string;
}

// 'WorkStudy' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Student' and 'Employee'.
// Named property 'somethingElse' of types 'Student' and 'Employee' are not identical.
interface WorkStudy extends Student, Employee{
    description:string;
}

If you want to reuse code, your only option will be to use composition over inheritance:
interface IStudent {
    name:string;
}

interface IEmployee {
    salary:number;
}

class Student implements IStudent {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class Employee implements IEmployee {
  constructor(public salary: number) {}
}

class WorkStudy implements IStudent, IEmployee{
  private _student: IStudent;
  private _employee: IEmployee;
  constructor(
    public description: string,
    student: IStudent,
    employee: IEmployee
  ) {
    this._employee = employee;
    this._student = student;
  }
  get salary() {
    return this._employee.salary;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._student.name;
  }
}

So, your only option is to adhere to the CRP.

"This is a design decision by the TypeScript team" - uh, no? Why do you write that?

When you are implementing a programming language, it is up to you as the designer to allow or disallow multiple inheritance. In this case, they choose not to support it. JS classes have a single inheritance but you need to remember that TypeScript was implemented long before JavaScript had classes. Disallowing multiple inheritance is always the most likely case because there are documented issues about the oppsosite.

TypeScript was based on the ES6 class proposals, it wasn't implemented before them. JS always had single inheritance, and it was never meant to gain multiple inheritance, so TypeScript designers were pretty much limited by that; it was not their decision.

Fair enough, I changed to the ECMAScript committee. The point I was trying to make is that having multiple or single inheritances has no "reason" other than a choice by the designers.
